# Avoid Duplicate records while inserting in MS SQL Server 2008 from a java program

Tags: java, oracle, sql-server-2008

I am working on a functionality where i am supposed to fetch data from oracle database and insert it into MSSQL Server 2008 Database Using Java Programming.(i know there are other alternatives like oracle golden gate,linked server.but this is what i am asked to do). I am able to fetch data from oracle server and insert it into sql server. But the issue is with the redunduncy. i.e Duplicate records get inserted whenever i trigger or run the program, as i am supposed to do it every 6,12,24 hours. i don't want it to happen. so how can i avoid it as the  source database has different connection and target database is different connection.

Following is the Code . Iwould like your help in working around to avoid duplicate data to be inserted.

```
/*TO Retrieve data from oracle database and insert it into sql server*/

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;


public class states {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String statecode, statename;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
                    .newInstance();

            // Connecting to Oracle
            Connection oracleconn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ipaddress:1521:orcl",
                    "uname", "pwd");
            // Connecting to SQL SERVER
            Connection sqlconn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbname;user=sa;password=pwd;");
            System.out.println("connected");



            // create Statement for sql and oracle

            /*
             * A Statement is an interface that represents a SQL statement. You
             * execute Statement objects, and they generate ResultSet objects,
             * which is a table of data representing a database result set. You
             * need a Connection object to create a Statement object.
             */
            Statement oraclestatement = oracleconn.createStatement();

            Statement sqlstatement = sqlconn.createStatement();

            /*
             * The ResultSet interface provides methods for retrieving and
             * manipulating the results of executed queries, and ResultSet
             * objects can have different functionality and characteristics.
             */
            ResultSet oracle_rs = oraclestatement
                    .executeQuery("select substr(TRIIDTX,1,2),TRINAMETX from  T_TRISTATE  WHERE TRIIDTX IS NOT NULL AND TRINAMETX IS NOT NULL AND TRINAMETX  not LIKE '%''%' ESCAPE '/'");
            System.out.println("TRICODETX   TRINAMETX \n");

            // String dummytable="tbldummystate";

            while (oracle_rs.next()) {

                System.out.println("     " + oracle_rs.getString(1) + "      "
                        + oracle_rs.getString(2) + "   ");

                // converting the string value into integer value

                statecode = oracle_rs.getString(1);
                statename = oracle_rs.getString(2);

                sqlstatement
                        .executeUpdate("insert into tblStates(StateCode,StateName) values('"
                                + statecode + "','" + statename + "')");

                // sqlstatement.execute ();


            }// end of while loop

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }// end of
}
```

Comment: if you don't want to eliminate duplicates using java you can declare a primary key index in the access db and catch the exception in your code.

Comment: i want to do it through the java code only,and the issue is i cannot change any thing in the client database that is the target table. it does not have any contraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) would do it?

Something like:

```
.executeUpdate("
MERGE INTO tblStates AS Target
USING (VALUES ('"+ statecode + "','" + statename + "'))
       AS Source (StateCode, StateName)
ON Target.StateCode = Source.StateCode
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (StateCode, StateName) VALUES ('"+ statecode + "','" + statename + "');
)";
```

Edit: if you want to update the StateName for a StateCode that already exists in the target table if it's changed in the source table you can add the following to the statement before the `WHEN NOT MATCHED`clause:

`WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET StateName = ('" + statename + "')"`

Comment: But how is that possible? when my source database is using another connection and statement and target using another connection and statement. one is oracle and another is sqlserver

Comment: The query only uses the connection to the SQL Server and does the insert only if the `StateCode`you provide with the variable doesn't already exist in the destination table. I haven't tried it in Java though only in T-SQL.

Comment: It works just like the insert you already do, but MERGE checks if the value already exists and only inserts if it doesn't.

Comment: ok. let me try it once again. what i was doing is create a dummy table in target database insert the value fetched from the source into the dummy table,check for existence of record between dummy table and target table using the query you mentioned,once inserted or updated,drop the dummy table. but that is not allowed  in the client side

Comment: @Mangesh Happy to help. If my answer was useful to you please consider upvoting it :) I revised it to include the case when you might want to update an existing value too.

Comment: Thanks i worked it our yesterday only. I could have up voted it but unfortunately it requires reputation of 15 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing the `insert into tblStates...` you could do a `select` on the `sqlconn` and check whether the record you want to insert does already exist. If so, skip the `insert`, otherwise, perform the `insert`.

However, this is not very efficient, as for each record, you will do a `select`. Imagine a table with 100k rows...

In order to improve performance, you could do the following. Before iterating over the `oracle_rs`, load **all** records from `tblStates` into a `List`. Since there is no primary key (according to your comments), I would suggest a `List<Foo>`, where you define a class named `Foo` containing the values for one row that is to be inserted in the target database. That allows you to do an in-memory check for existence in your target database. If your in-memory collection contains the record that you just fetched from the source database, do not insert it into the target database.

In pseudo-code, it would roughly look like this:

```
String selectAllQuery = "select StateCode, StateName from tblStates";
Statement selectAllstatement = sqlconn.createStatement();
ResultSet selectAllResultset = selectAllstatement.executeQuery(selectAllQuery);

List<Foo> cache = new ArrayList<Foo>();
while (selectAllResultset.next()) {
    cache.add(new Foo(selectAllResultset.getString("StateCode"),
                      selectAllResultset.getString("StateName")));
}

while (oracle_rs.next()) {
    statecode = oracle_rs.getString(1);
    statename = oracle_rs.getString(2);

    if (!cache.contains(new Foo(statecode,
                                statename))) {
        sqlstatement.executeUpdate("insert into tblStates"
            + "(StateCode,StateName) values('"
            + statecode + "','" + statename + "')");
    }
}
```

With a `Foo` class like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private String stateName;
    private String stateCode;
    // Insert constructor with two arguments
    // Insert equals() implementation based on the two instance variables
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.i will try it. if you could give me a small example of the same that would be great. because i am pretty new to it.

Comment: I Tried your solution but its not working either, its repeatedly inserting the duplicate rows,which are previously present

Comment: Then there must be a mistake somewhere, maybe you can update your question, or start a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) in order to ask for suggestions / help.